# Can I change the app screen after receiving the success action via react-saga?

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

I'm trying to implement a login flow using react-saga.

I created three actions: REQ_LOGIN, SUCCESS_LOGIN, FAIL_LOGIN,

I succeeded in accessing the reducer by calling REQ_LOGIN to retrieve data from the server and then executing the SUCCESS_LOGIN action.

However, after a successful login, the token value must be saved in AsyncStorage and the view must be switched through react-navigation.

But can't this be done in the reducer? Through the 'navigation' parameter of the '(react-navigation) library', when the SUCCESS_LOGIN action is executed, the screen must be changed.

I don't know what to do

Comment: Have you read this article? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

Comment: Hi I think above article will be help on your concern; once the app state relevant to the SUCCESS_LOGIN changed you can switch the navigation stack using switch navigator. It is the most convenient way as I think.

Comment: With regards to your question about why this can't be done directly in your reducer - reducers should be pure/side-effect free, so doing things like setting items in `AsyncStorage` or calling methods with side-effects from other modules is discouraged. If you're using `redux-saga` you could have a saga listen for the `SUCCESS_LOGIN` action and perform side effects from the saga.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggestion you use another approach: instead of keeping token in AsyncStorage directly you can save it in your store (if you use redux or in another store manager) and use persist library (for example [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) for Redux) which also can keep your data into AsyncStorage and in additional provide ability for rehydrating.